# Prim's algorithm on existing graph

Tags: matplotlib, graph, networkx, prims-algorithm

I plotted a graph using text input file now I have to apply prim's algorithm to it. How can I do it ? Below is my code for generating a graph using a text file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

f= open('input10.txt')
G=nx.Graph()
x=f.read()
x=x.split()
y=[float(i) for i in x]

for i in range(1,30,3):
        G.add_node(y[i],pos=(y[i+1],y[i+2]))

def last_index(y):
    return len(y)-1
z=last_index(y)

for i in range(31,z-3,5):
    G.add_edge(y[i],y[i+1],weight=(y[i+2]))

pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
weight=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
plt.figure()
nx.draw(G,pos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the nodes u=y[i], v=y[i+1] and weight=y[i+2], and create adjacency matrix or adjacency list of the graph and then apply prim's algorithm, you can find a good and easy tutorial here :[Prim’s Minimum Spanning Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-greedy-algo-5/)

Comment: Thanks for support. I managed to do it by converting graph to an adjacency matrix using A = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G,G.node()).